Constraining out a region in objective function with OpenMDAO ExecComp
I'm trying to solve for a flight trajectory around (and not over) a rectangular obstacle in the x-y plane. My first attempt at doing this was to create four linked phases, each one within a constrained region (constraints on the x, y and z coordinates), linked at the end points. However, this seems to struggle to converge, and has some unexpected behaviour (e.g. plotting the state discretisation nodes while solving, the trajectory has some large kinks in it when I'd expect it to be a smooth oval (minimising squared integrated throttle)). Perhaps linking four trajectories in a circle is a particularly demanding set of constrains for the optimiser to satisfy?
The other way I can think to do it is to use a single phase linked to itself and penalise the optimiser if the trajectory falls within the footprint of the building. A rectangle can be constructed as the product of two sums of hyperbolic tangent functions, and this can be added into the objective as a smooth penalty, so that the objective function looks something like this:
    # Add the building constraints
    h = 10000
    k = 10000
    x0 = 10
    x1 = 50
    y0 = 20
    y1 = 100

    prob.model.add_subsystem('obj', om.ExecComp("v = sum_throttle_effort + h*sum((tanh(k*(x - x0))+1) - (tanh(k*(x - x1))+1))*(tanh(k*(y - y0))+1) - (tanh(k*(y - y1))+1)))",
                                                h={'val': h},
                                                k={'val': k},
                                                x0={'val': x0},
                                                x1={'val': x1},
                                                y0={'val': y0},
                                                y1={'val': y1},
                                                x={'shape_by_conn':True},
                                                y={'shape_by_conn':True}
                                                ))
    
    # Link to position states
    prob.model.connect('traj.phase0.timeseries.x', 'obj.x')
    prob.model.connect('traj.phase0.timeseries.y', 'obj.y')

    prob.model.add_objective('obj.v')

where k is the 'verticalness' of the building sides (the greater the better) and h is a large constant to penalise being within the region of the building. However, I've only ever used this approach before to connect single values with the ExecComp, using src_indices in prob.model.connect. Is it possible for this objective function to be large whenever any of the state discretisation nodes are within the building region? This is what I've tried to accomplish with the sum in the objective function and the 'shape_by_conn' arguments, but these are largely guesses.
Or maybe this is the wrong approach entirely, and there's another reason why the linked phases aren't working?
